# Apache2 proxy showing 2 slots and PIDs?

Tags: apache, tomcat, apache2

I'm running one single `tomcat` webserver behind an `apache2` proxy. But 
`localhost:443/status` shows:

```
Slot    PID     Stopping    Connections         Threads     Async connections
                            total   accepting   busy  idle  writing keep-al closing
0       1578    no          0       yes         0     25    0       0       0
1       1577    no          1       yes         1     24    0       1       0
Sum     2       0           1                   1     49    0       1       0
```

I wonder why I might have 2 PIDs running? Especially what I don't like is that apache has 50 workers, but reserves 25 worker threads for each of the PID. Ideally I'd want to to have all 50 workers reserved for the tomcat server.

Could this be due to my setup of 2 virtual hosts in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mypage.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
      ..
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
      Redirect / https:myserver.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm just having this to redirect any non-https requests. Could this trigger those 2 PIDs? If yes: most likely only a few requests will come on port 80, so I would want to assign most of the workers to the https host. Is that possible?

What I also noticed: `ps aux | grep apache2` gives 5 processes:

```
www-data  1577  0.0  0.1 2090340 14644 ?       Sl   06:25   0:04 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1578  0.0  0.1 2024812 12948 ?       Sl   06:25   0:05 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      1679  0.0  0.1  92580  8196 ?        Ss   Jan08   0:44 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1757  0.0  0.0  19904   172 ?        Ss   Jan08   0:29 /usr/bin/htcacheclean -d 120 -p /var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk -l 300M -n
mysshusr 19322  0.0  0.0  14856  1100 pts/0    S+   10:53   0:00 grep --color=auto apache2
```

Are those the worker threads?

Comment: _Is that possible?_ I think that NO, but you can start 2 Apache servers, each one listening on one port only (obviously one for :80 and the other one for :443). Do you believe you would improve the server's performance ?

Comment: Ok so if the 2 PIDs come from virtual hosts configuration, how can I tell apache to no split the available workers to both hosts, but assign the workers mainly to the 443 host?

Comment: I didn't say that. You have as many process as StartServers say to have. Please read the [doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#startservers). To assign workers, I gave you a solution.